# Handle all requests on asp.net empty web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, http-status-code-404, global-asax

I want to handle all the requests. **I cannot handle the requests that have an extension**. Let me show you what I mean.

### 1) First Let me show you what my web application has: (it is very simple)

**Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Handle404.aspx">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="Handle404.aspx" />
    </customErrors>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

**Global.asax**

```
using System;

namespace DeleteMeWebAppliation
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Test");
        }

        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx**

```
using System;

namespace DeleteMeWebAppliation
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
}
```

**Handle404.aspx**

```
using System;

namespace DeleteMeWebAppliation
{
    public partial class Handle404 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.Write("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

### 2) Now here is the problem:

**Note I have a breakpoint on all the lines `Console.Write("Test")` my goal is to handle all the requests. **In other words I want to hit the breakpoint every time I make a request to IIS regardless of the url.**

a) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/` **It Works** (I hit a breakpoint)

b) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/SomeNoneExistingPage.aspx` **It Works** (I hit a breakpoint)

c) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/Foooooo` **It Works** (I hit a breakpoint)

d) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/Foooooo/fooo/fooo/test.aspx` **It Works** (I hit a breakpoint)

e) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/foo.test` **It FAILS** (I HIT NO BREAKPOINT) **Why does breakpoint on method Application_Error does not hit!?**

e) When I go to `http://localhost:65284/foo/foo.jpg` **It FAILS** (I HIT NO BREAKPOINT) **Why does breakpoint on method Application_Error does not hit!?**

**In summary how can I execute my custom code when someone goes to `http://localhost:65284/foo.test`** for example. Everything works great but the moment I go to a url that has a '.' with something else rather than aspx at the end then it fails!

There are a lot of places on the internet that show how to handle 404 errors but for some reason I cannot make it work.

---

This is what I get when I go to `http://localhost:65284/foo.test` I get a 404 error and for some reason I do not get redirected to the 404 handler. I get redirected if the link ends in aspx. It makes no sense

[image]

Comment: I am running IIS version 10. This happens to me when I publish it to an IIS server and also when running on IIS Exrpress

Comment: What does the web browser show when it loads `http://localhost:65284/foo/foo.jpg`?

Comment: Sounds like you need to enable RAMFAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you were able to apply the proper solution. In case you are still wanting to know the answer the questions below:

"e) When I go to http://localhost:65284/foo.test It FAILS (I HIT NO BREAKPOINT) Why does breakpoint on method Application_Error does not hit!?

e) When I go to http://localhost:65284/foo/foo.jpg It FAILS (I HIT NO BREAKPOINT) Why does breakpoint on method Application_Error does not hit!?"

The reason these did not redirect in your earlier configuration is that the  tag applies to valid page requests and only gets applied once a request gets "handled". Your request never got past the handlers in IIS.

I think the following illustrates the flow relatively well:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture/_static/image1.png

You custom handler `HandleAllRequestsHandler` would fall under the module section.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution.

**Web Config Looks like:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>    
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*" type="HandleAllRequestsHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add verb="*" path="*" name="ImageWatermarkHandler" type="HandleAllRequestsHandler"/>
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

And now I handle all requests with this handler:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

public class HandleAllRequestsHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test!");
    }

    public bool IsReusable => false;
}
```

Note I handle all requests in here because the verb and path have values `*`. Place your custom filter in there